# Displaying WordPress Blog Articles Sorted by Date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I use this code to sort articles on blog section of my website.

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

When I use this code all articles gets sorted well but when I change the category same articles show up. So no matter which category I select, same articles show up.

I found cat array but it won't help me because There are multiple categories to be displayed by category.php file... If I use

Articles gets displayed by category but sorting won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to filter by category if you want to avoid all of them showing up all the time but you don't necessarily need to use `cat` to do so. You can add the option to your query array this way:

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ),
);// This will display posts that have categories 2 AND 6

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ),
);// This will display posts that have categories 2 OR 6 (not children of that category)
```

You can check the different options in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).